# Bootstrap4: Accordion collapse not smooth

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I made accordion collapse in bootstrap 4. It works, but it's not smooth does someone know how to fix this? I've tried making another div and put div's inside, but nothing.
here's the code. thanks!

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<section>
  <div class="container-fluid bg-light ">
    <div id="accordion">
      <div class="text-center pt-5 pb-4 mt-5 pt-4">
        <h2 id="price">Our prices</h2>
        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="myGroup" class="d-flex align-items-center pt-4 justify-content-center flex-md-row flex-wrap">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column col-md-4 col-lg-3 ">
          <a href="#classy" data-toggle="collapse" aria-controls="classy" id="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-lg mb-3" aria-expanded="true">Classy</a>
          <a href="#casual" data-toggle="collapse" aria-controls="casual" id="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-lg mb-3 collapsed" aria-expanded="false">Casual</a>
          <a href="#jackets" data-toggle="collapse" aria-controls="jackets" id="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-lg mb-3 collapsed" aria-expanded="false">Jacket</a>
        </div>
        <div id="classy" class="collapse show card col-md-4 col-lg-3 px-0 ml-4 my-5 " data-parent="#accordion">
          <ul class="list-group list-group-flush cards" id="cards">
            <li class="list-group-item">Suit</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="casual" class="collapse card col-md-4 col-lg-3 px-0 ml-4 my-5" data-parent="#accordion">
          <ul class="list-group list-group-flush cards" id="cards">
            <li class="list-group-item">farmerki...........</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="jackets" class="collapse card col-md-4 col-lg-3 px-0 ml-4 my-5" data-parent="#accordion">
          <ul class="list-group list-group-flush cards" id="cards">
            <li class="list-group-item">jakna...........</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Please update the snippet to ensure there is a [minimal-reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I think it is missing some JS from bootstrap? I tried adding the CSS, but it seems the accordion behavior does not work with that alone. Thanks!

Comment: nothing is missing, there is a CSS just for the buttons to be rounded. Everything else is like that.

Answer (score 1):

## Hello

Please you can try to use this is pure bootstrap 4 accordion this is very smooth but

### NB: It should use in your website  Here is a [demo](https://codepen.io/mrana/pen/QWbqjvX)  try to visit it

```css
#accordion .collapsing {
    transition: height 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<section>
  <div class="container-fluid bg-light ">
    <div id="accordion">
      <div class="text-center pt-5 pb-4 mt-5 pt-4">
        <h2 id="price">Our prices</h2>
        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="accordion">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-6">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                  <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                    Collapsible Group Item #1
                  </button>
                </h5>
              </div>
            </div> 
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                  <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                    Collapsible Group Item #1
                  </button>
                </h5>
              </div>
            </div> 
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                  <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                    Collapsible Group Item #1
                  </button>
                </h5>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6">
              <div class="card">
                <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordion">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                    </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```